# font-size in Chrome with animations doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox

It seems like the font-size with animations doesn't work correctly.  Anything below font-size: 6px doesn't change the size of the element.  This seems to be a new things and works correctly in Firefox.  See example below.

Edit:

- Chrome Version: **73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)**
- Minimum font size is set to **Tiny**

**Chrome**
[image]

**Firefox**
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/72tdqxme/7/

```
.loader {
    margin-left: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-size: 2px;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-right: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-left: 1.1em solid #ffffff;
    -webkit-animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
    animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
}

.loader, .loader:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load8 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(.3);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes load8 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: The message telling that you must include a code snippet when linking to jsfiddle is there for a reason... Working around it by entering this fake code block sounds like an insult.

Comment: Ps: no need for all the code in your fiddle, just try to set a text's font-size to 2px and check its computed value (will be `6px`). https://jsfiddle.net/5xvbfkgj/

Comment: @Kaiido again the issues is when there is an animation, the font-size on text works correctly.

Comment: Known bug, you'll have to wait. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=949471 I definitely have 6px returned in my fiddle and also definitely see the bug even when no animation is set: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhf2u34w/

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-text-size-adjust` is no longer working after `Chrome 27`.

Try using `transform`

```
font-size:12px;
transform: scale(0.833);
```

Comment: scale can be used under keyframes

Comment: You can specify multiple transforms, as a space separated list, in the same declaration (when using multiple declarations in the same block, the last one will override previous ones). `transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.833);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me in Chrome v73. Perhaps your Chrome user profile has a minimum font-size set (do a search for "font" in Chrome's settings)?

Comment: Checked the settings and its set to Tiny

Answer (score -1):

Try Using em instead of px in a font-size because em is relative to the font size of its direct or nearest parent

Comment: Using `em`, same things happens but works in Firefox.